# How to select and print all articles of current user using JavaScript and MonoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function

With the following function i get all articles:

```
getAllPost: (req, res) => {
        Article.find({}).limit().populate('author').then(articles => {
            res.render('home/AllPost',{
                articles
            });
        });
    }
```

I want do display the articles of current logged in user but im not sure how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) method to run a pipeline that has a **[`$lookup stage`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** to do a "left-join" on the `articles` collection for a particular user. Consider the following example:

```
getAllPost: (req, res) => {
    User.aggregate([
        /* filter users collection for current user given by req.user._id */
        { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.Objectid(req.user._id) } },

        /* perform a "left-join" to the articles collection 
           and store the results in an array "articles" 
        */
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "articles",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "author",
                "as": "articles"
            }
        }
    ]).exec().then(results => {
        let articles;
        if (!results.length) {
            articles = [];
        } else {
            articles = results[0].articles;            
        }

        res.render('home/AllPost', { articles });        
    })
}
```